# Add delay of 1 second to a loop?

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a 1 second delay inside a loop.

What I have done is:

```
public void Delay()
{
    DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);

    while (DateTime.Now <= end)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

and I add the Delay() in my loop.

Is this the best/acceptable way of doing this or can someone recommend a better way?

Comment: If you can afford to stop the whole thread, you can just use `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. It stops the execution of the thread for 1000ms.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing Thread.Sleep(1000) like you have been suggested to will block the current running thread. In case this is not a problem (if this is the only thread), no reason not to do it.

Comment: @Veverke I would say it is not an issue if the thread is not doing anything else.

Answer (score 11):

```
Thread.Sleep (1000);
```

This 1000 is time duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try Thread.Sleep();

```
using System.Threading;
Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1000 milliseconds i.e 1sec
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to do it:

```
public void Delay(int seconds)
{
    //DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
    //while (DateTime.Now <= end)
    //{
    //}
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(seconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Piero, if you want to abstract the milliseconds and deal only with seconds, there is no need to take care of the conversion, the Sleep has an overload that accepts a TimeSpan. The same would be accomplished directly with `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`.

Comment: I didn't know it

Comment: thanks. its working now.

Comment: @AseemMalhotra Good! So, sign it as solution ;)